# Spring Cloud Config Server does not serve application-specific properties in native mode

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I have a Spring Cloud Config Server v3.0.5 which serves configuration properties from a Git repository like this:

```sh
|
|-- foo-service/
|   |-- application.yml
|-- bar-service/
|   |-- application.yml
|-- application-common.yml
|-- application-kafka.yml
|-- ...
```

As you can see, there is a sub-directory for each microservice that contains application-specific configurations and some common configurations in the root directory that we can fetch by profiles (common, kafka etc.)

So, for example, we can fetch *application-specific and/or profile-specific config properties* like this:

```sh
# Successfully returns application-specific properties
curl http://<CONFIG_SERVICE_URL>/foo-service-application.yml
# Successfully returns application-specific + common + kafka properties
curl http://<CONFIG_SERVICE_URL>/foo-service-application,common,kafka.yml
```

But, during development, we'd like to use a native file-based repository so that we don't need to commit every config change and test it locally easily.

So, in the config server, I've set active profiles to `native` and also set `spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations` to the same repository path.

But when I try to fetch application-specific configurations (i.e. config files in sub-directories), it returns empty:

```sh
# This returns empty response:
curl http://<CONFIG_SERVICE_URL>/foo-service-application.yml
{}

# This returns only profile-specific configs but **omits** foo-service applcations configs:
curl http://<CONFIG_SERVICE_URL>/foo-service-application,common,kafka.yml
...
```

What am I missing here? Why can't it also return application-specific properties? Do I have to set yet another configuration for the config server?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally found it! 
Apparently, we need to explicitly specify the subdirectories with an *application placeholder* in the `spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations` property which is IMO vaguely described [here in docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_file_system_backend):

> The search locations can contain placeholders for {application}, {profile}, and {label}. In this way, you can segregate the directories in the path and choose a strategy that makes sense for you (such as subdirectory per application or subdirectory per profile).

So, in my case, I had to define the `search-locations` as this:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
         search-locations:
          - /path/to/config/repo
          - /path/to/config/repo/{application}
```

Now it can properly serve both *application-specific and profile-specific* config properties.

Although this suffices for my case, I still have no clue why the file-based and the git-based approaches differ so much (i.e. why should we explicitly set subdirectories for application-specific configs in a file-based approach whereas it can automatically serve them in the git-based approach?)